How to create a New Relic ping monitor
I created new account for new relic - on a free tier. And want to run a monitor to check the health of my webapp.
According to their documentation it should be possible to execute up to 500 synthetic checks in a month.
But it does not allow me to create any of the monitors. During the creation of most of them there is a message "We cannot temporarily fetch your monthly allowance of synthetic checks", for ping monitors there are no messages but still I cannot save it.
I tried to reload the page and waited couple of days - message is the same.
When I check my usage according to the docs:

What can I do? Support cases are not available for a free tier...

are you trying to create these monitors just after creating the free account?
Sometimes, it takes few days for entitlements to fully propagate to your account and that could be the reason.
